# How to instantiate a logger implementing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T> that logs to Serilog logger

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, serilog, ilogger

How do I instantiate a logger implementing `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<out TCategoryName>` that will output logs to my Serilog logger, when I cannot do it via standard ASP.NET Core dependency injection?

I have Serilog configured in my ASP.NET Core project, and the standard dependency injection set up is correctly injecting loggers into my controllers and services. The output from these loggers is correctly written to the file as specified in my Serilog configuration.

However, I need to pass a logger to an object that is instantiated during `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)`, so I cannot resolve it via DI. I can instantiate a `Serilog.Logger`, but since I want to avoid direct dependencies on Serilog outside of my configuration code, I am forced to use my own adaptor. I would expect there to be some existing adaptor that would use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<out TCategoryName>`, but I can't work out how to do it.

The precise use case is to inject a logger into a `DbCommandInterceptor`, which I am trying to do inside `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)`:

```cs
var databaseConfiguration = this.Configuration
    .GetSection(nameof(DatabaseConfiguration))
    .Get<DatabaseConfiguration>();
var interceptor = new LoggingDbCommandInterceptor(
    warning => Log.Logger.Warning("{Warning}", warning),
    error => Log.Logger.Error("{Error}", error),
    databaseConfiguration);
var dbConfiguration = new MyDbConfiguration(interceptor);
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(dbConfiguration);
```

Comment: If that object is configured in `ConfigureServices` you *can* resolve the logger using DI. Post your code please

Comment: At the very least you can use one of the `Add` methods that accepts a factory with an `IServiceprovider` parameter and generate the logger there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've posted the code where I am resorting to passing some actions in for logging to `LoggingDbComandInterceptor`, but would refer to replace them with an `ILogger<T>`. The objects I'm creating are required for the static call to `DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(...)`, and I can't see a nice way to resolve them without instantiating an intermediate service provider, and I can't see how to do it using the AddXXX methods either.

Comment: The question doesn't contain any code. `LoggingDbComandInterceptor` probably means you're trying to log SQL commands. Which ORM are you using? EF Core uses `ILogger` directly, you just have to enable it

Comment: I hadn't clicked "Save" yet :)

Comment: Which ORM are you using? Perhaps all you need is to configure the ORM to log queries?

Comment: I'm using EF6. I can log all SQL commands by injecting a logger into my DbContext, but I want to use an interceptor to target slow and failing commands, as per https://romiller.com/2016/02/11/ef6-x-correlating-poor-performing-sql-to-application-code/
I can't see a nicer way to configure an interceptor when using EF5 in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: With just EF6, you could register the interceptor once, probably as a Transient or Scoped instance, use a constructor accepting that interceptor in all your DbContexts and DI would resolve both automatically. It looks like the problem is the static class here (and calling a context Configuration is suspicious too)

Comment: Besides, DbConfiguration isn't something that needs DI. In ASP.NET Old it's found automagically by EF. In ASP.NET Core - there are no AppDomains to begin with, so I don't know if it would work or not. Is that the problem you encountered?

Comment: I didn't even try to let the DbConfiguration be located automagically (or specified in an attribute on the DbContext), since I don't think that will let me inject a logger into it.
That's the exact problem I have: how to inject the logger into the interceptor.
If I was using EF Core, I could use `AddDbContext(options => ...)` and call `AddInterceptors` inside there, but can see no equivalent approach using EF6.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer, and a bunch of other helpful tips here:
https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/

```cs
var loggerFactory = (ILoggerFactory)new LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog(serilogLogger);
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TCategoryName>();
```